# python GUI FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Tags: python, user-interface

I have the following code where I'm trying to allow the user to open three different files and once the user has selected them, I would like the code to read and subtract them through python GUI.

However, I'm having difficulties using with open to enable the code read the three files and then by clicking view to subtract them where it produces an two errors.Does anyone know how I can arrange to do this! Thanks for the help!

```
  return self.func(*args)
```

```
    with open('CHGCAR1', 'r') as f:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'CHGCAR1'
```

```
def charge_density():
     with open('CHGCAR1', 'r') as f:
            CHGCAR1 = f.read()
            CHGCAR1_ints = [safeFloat(x) for x in CHGCAR1.split()]
            print(CHGCAR1_ints)
            CHGCAR1_ints_1 = [c for c in CHGCAR1_ints if c is not None]
            print(CHGCAR1_ints_1)
     with open('CHGCAR2', 'r') as f:
            CHGCAR2 = f.read()
            CHGCAR2_ints = [safeFloat(x) for x in CHGCAR2.split()]
            print(CHGCAR2_ints)
            CHGCAR2_ints_2 = [c for c in CHGCAR2_ints if c is not None]
            print(CHGCAR2_ints_2)
     with open('CHGCAR3', 'r') as f:
            CHGCAR3 = f.read()
            CHGCAR3_ints = [safeFloat(x) for x in CHGCAR3.split()]
            print(CHGCAR3_ints)
            CHGCAR3_ints_3 = [c for c in CHGCAR3_ints if c is not None]
            print(CHGCAR3_ints_3)
     
     with open("CHGCAR_final.txt", 'w') as f:
            for i in range( min( len(CHGCAR1_ints_1), len(CHGCAR2_ints_2), len(CHGCAR3_ints_3)) ) :
             f.write(str(CHGCAR1_ints_1[i] - CHGCAR2_ints_2[i] - CHGCAR3_ints_3[i]))
            f.write(' ')
            print(f)
```

Comment: that error means the file does not actually exist. does it possibly have an actual file extension where it's saved on your computer?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.